# pandas: How to create DataFrame from rows extracted using iterrows()?

Tags: python, pandas

I have a large dataset, and am trying to group certain rows by a specific condition (in this case, by all except the last two letters of a word, i.e some_string[-1]).

I first select the rows and store them in a dictionary with the keys as the first part of the word, and the values as a list of tuples of rows that fulfil that condition.

(I don't know if this is the best method, please feel free to suggest!)

```
def group_by_name(data, name_column): 
  #simple grouping of bookings according to everything except last two letters of name
  buckets = {};
  i =0;
  for index,booking in data.iterrows():
      buckets.setdefault(str(booking[name_column])[:-1],[]).append((index,booking))
  return buckets
```

This returns a list of objects per key - how can I recast these objects into a dataframe such that I can read and manipulate them further more easily?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you need [groupby](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/groupby.html):

```
data = pd.DataFrame({  'D':[1,3,5,7,1],
                   'E':[5,3,6,9,2],
                   'F':['asd','tty','tty','tty','asd']})

print (data)
   D  E    F
0  1  5  asd
1  3  3  tty
2  5  6  tty
3  7  9  tty
4  1  2  asd

for i, g in data.groupby(data['F'].str[:-2]):
    print (i)
    print (g)

a
   D  E    F
0  1  5  asd
4  1  2  asd
t
   D  E    F
1  3  3  tty
2  5  6  tty
3  7  9  tty
```

Comment: Yes, groupby was what I was looking for! Using .apply also worked better than the syntax above. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

This might be of some help

```
df[df['A'] > 0]
                A         B         C         D     E   0
2000-01-01  0.469112 -0.282863 -1.509059 -1.135632 NaN NaN
2000-01-02  1.212112 -0.173215  0.119209 -1.044236 NaN NaN
2000-01-04  7.000000 -0.706771 -1.039575  0.271860 NaN NaN
2000-01-07  0.404705  0.577046 -1.715002 -1.039268 NaN NaN
```

Check out pandas documentation [here](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/indexing.html#indexing-boolean) might help you refine the above logic you want.